# Update options select attributes according to the other select tag with the help of Ajax and Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have the select tag and a series of options select attributes with their values and inner text stored in the database.

This is the way I am displaying the data on view, by calling a foreach for each select tag, 2 in total:

```
{!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
<select class="form-control category_id" name="category_id">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value='{{ $category->id }}'> {{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

{!! Form::label('subcategory_id', 'Subcategory:') !!}
<select class="form-control" name="subcategory_id" label="Subcategory">
    @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <option value='{{ $subcategory->id }}'> {{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

The problem, is that I am stuck with the following idea: The category and the subcategory are in one to many relationship, that means that when the user clicks a certain category, the select subcategory should be populated only with the values linked to the category chosen.

How can I find a solution to this problem, I am thinking about creating an ajax request but I can't figure how to populate the option select attributes. Or create a JSON (all the work on front-end) variable to store the subcategories and just update the select tag accordingly to what category user chose.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

***VIEW:***

```
{!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category:') !!}
<select class="form-control" id="categories" name="category_id">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value='{{ $category->id }}'> {{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<div id="displayCategories" style="display:none">
    {!! Form::label('subcategory_id', 'Subcategory:') !!}
    <select class="form-control" id="subcategories" name="subcategory_id" label="Subcategory">
        @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
            <option value='{{ $subcategory->id }}'> {{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

***JS & JQUERY & AJAX:***

```
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
 integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('#categories').on('change',function(e) {
    var cat_id = e.target.value;
    //ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ajax-subcat/{cat_id}', //note:that the path can be different for different purpose used, in a simple page -> '/ajax-subcat/{cat_id}' so use the console of your browser
        type: 'GET',
        data: {cat_id : cat_id},
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#subcategories').empty();
            $('#displayCategories').show();
            $.each(response, function(index, subcatObj) {
                $('#subcategories').append('<option value="' + subcatObj.id + '">' + subcatObj.name + '</option>');
                console.log(subcatObj);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

***ROUTE:***

```
Route::get('ajax-subcat/{cat_id}', 'PostController@getAjax');
```

***CONTROLLER:***

```
public function getAjax() 
{
   $cat_id = Input::get('cat_id');
   $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', $cat_id)->get();
   return Response::json($subcategories);
}
```

Don't forget to introduce in the controller the corresponding models, facades for Input and Response. *In my case:*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Category;
use App\Subcategory;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention the version of Laravel you using so the implementation maybe slightly different. You can do it via the ajax method. You could look into [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for the frontend calls but you will need to setup event listeners on the select element for when the user makes a new selection.

Comment: Latest version of Laravel, 5.4